# Entity Framework Migration to Update existing many-to-many to 2x one to many

Tags: entity-framework

I've an existing relationship between two entities (many-to-many). Let's say something like this:

```
public class TypeA
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<TypeB> TypeBs {get;set;}
}

public class TypeB
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<TypeA> TypeAs {get;set;}
}
```

Entity Framework generates a table for the many-to-many as an internal. However, I would like to add custom properties to this generated table. I've read some other questions/answers where they say: create a new entity and do one-to-many from both existing entities to the new entity. Of course this will work, but I'm not sure what the best way is to add a migration in a way that Entity Framework let's me keep the generated table without loosing data.

Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I believe if you create an entity for the junction table, make sure it has the same name as the automatically created one, and make sure that all of the fk/pk fields have the same name and scheme, it will "just work".  You *may* have to slightly modify the migration generated scaffolding code to not try to create the new table though.  If you don't want to keep the same names (some of the generated names can be ugly), you would have to manually move the data in the migration upgrade code.